# Using app.yaml in Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm running a Java app on AppEngine, and I want to use app.yaml. I've read the docs and created a app.yaml app inside the WEB-INF folder with the following contents

```
application: myprojectname
version: 1
runtime: java
api_version: 1

welcome_files:
  - index.jsp
  - index.html

handlers:
- url: /oblivion/*
  servlet: myprojectname.CronUpdater
```

Where myprojectname is the name of the project.

However when I access localhost:8888/oblivion Or  localhost:8888/oblivion/ I get a

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /oblivion. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

What could be the reason?

This is the structure of the directory (truncated)

```
pratik@pratik-desktop:~/workspace/myprojectname/war$ ls -LR
index.html  index.jsp  WEB-INF

./WEB-INF:
appengine-generated  app.yaml  cron.yaml  logging.properties
appengine-web.xml    classes   lib        web.xml

...
```

Comment: You also don't need the 'api_version: 1' line

Answer (score 4):

In appengine, there is two environment type (as of now) :

- Flexible Environment
- Standard Environment

You can't use  `appengine-web.xml` and `app.yaml` at the same time :

- **Flexible environment** use `app.yaml` to configure all the things that appengine need to know
- **Standard environment** use `appengine-web.xml` and `logging.properties`

Here I assume you want to use the appengine in '**Flexible Environment**' mode. Usually, the `app.yaml` is located in the `appengine` folder, just inside your `main` folder.

From the [Google Cloud Platform doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9), you should have :

```
myprojectname/
 [pom.xml]         (optional, only if you use maven)
 [build.gradle]    (optional, only if you use gradle)
 [index.yaml]      (optional, only if you use cloud datastore)
 [cron.yaml]       (optional, only if you use cron job)
 [dispatch.yaml]   (optional, only if you route to services)
 src/main/
   appengine/
     app.yaml
   java/
     com.example.mycode/
       MyCode.java
   webapp/
     [index.html]
     [index.jsp]
     WEB-INF/
       [web.xml]
```

One last thing : handlers should be defined in the `web.xml` file. In `app.yaml`, you should just have :

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

and in your `web.xml` something like this :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CronUpdater</servlet-name>
      <servlet-path>myprojectname.CronUpdater</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CronUpdater</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oblivion/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Docs here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#app-engine-api-migration suggest that for the standard environment you replace appengine-web.xml for app.yaml. I know this answer is old, but maybe requires updating?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using myprojectname.CronUpdater, you need to list the full package and class of the servlet. So if CronUpdater is in package

`com.mycompany.servlets`

you'll need to put

`servlet: com.mycompany.servlets.CronUpdater`

in your app.yaml.

Comment: But when I run the server. Using Run -> Run.. it compiles, it is as if it ignores the .yaml file.

Comment: Of course it compiles, javac has no idea about the app.yml file. You need to put the fully qualified class name of the servlet or the container will not find your code.